# Can a non-US registered aircraft be based in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, aircraft-ownership

I am a Swiss citizen and I might have to move to the US for a couple of years. I own a small plane in Switzerland (HB-registered) and I'd like to take it with me to the US. As my stay in the US would be for a relatively short period of time, I'd like to keep it HB-registered. Is it possible to do that knowing that the plane would be based and primarily used in the US for that period of time?

Comment: I can't find any kind of maximum duration visit in 14 CFR.  I'd recommend calling the FSDO nearest your intended location.

Comment: Here is the website with contact information for the FAA Aircraft Registration Branch in Oklahoma City, OK. They should be able to help you: [FAA Aircraft Registration](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/contact_aircraft_certification)

Comment: I would recommend comparing the cost/effort of getting your plane across the Atlantic (twice) compared to renting something once you are in the US

Comment: @MaxR thanks for you advices I will definitelly contact them!

Comment: @757toga thanks for you advices I will definitelly contact them!

Comment: @EugeneStyer Is it easy to rent a plane for a several weeks (to explore the country during holyday) in the US? Because in Switzerland it's a huge pain, nobody will rent you a plane for more than a couple of days. That's why I chose to buy...

Comment: @Shadow_Heart The whole "bring vs rent" decision is indeed complicated.  There are some places that do long term rentals, where you lease a plane for 6 months, but they are not common.  I agree that most FBOs focus on training and that makes it very hard to do long-term rentals.  Getting a less-flown SR20 for a week or two may be easier than getting a heavily-flown 172.  Again, try calling several FBOs in your destination area before deciding.  Your usage patterns matter--over the 2 years, how many total hours do you expect?  And how many longer trips beyond 3-4 days do you expect?

Comment: @MaxR It's difficult to say how much time I'll have to fly when in the US, but here in Switzerland I usually fly aroud 60-70 hours a year and go for longer trips 2 times a year.

Comment: @Shadow_Heart You may find that wherever you are going, there are clubs that would work.  A shareowner club doesn't work well for say, a 6 month stent but two years is long enough to justify it.  A 4-5 plane club might cost 5,000 to 10,000 USD to buy into, but you would get that back when you sell your share down the road.  A lot of clubs are set up in such a way that 5-10 hours per month is easy to schedule, and a week or two trip once a year would work fine.